# I am trying to lookup several unique names in 6 columns

Tags: r, unique

I am trying to lookup several names in data frames. Examples below where " Names " would be the df. I am curious why I can't get the unique data for the whole set.

```
unique(Names[1:3])
#Names is the df they are in, this has been giving me a table with all the names

unique(Names$colname)
#Has been working but this method won't filter out unique names for each column bc its diff commands
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome!  In the future, please use `dput()` to provide a reproducible sample of data like `Names`.  As it stands, you need to take your `Names` dataframe, which is in fact a (named) `list` of vectors (columns), and **`unlist()`** it before using `unique()`: `unique(unlist(Names[1:3]))`. This consolidates all the targeted data into a single vector, on which `unique()` can now operate.

Comment: @Greg so essentially, I need to take It out of a df bc unique() wont work for that, It needs a vector. And sorry I tried using the three tick marks I don't think it came out right.

Comment: Did my suggestion end up working for you?  Namely `unique(unlist(Names[1:3]))`, or with the native [`|>`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/the-new-r-pipe/) pipe available in R 4.1 or greater: `Names[1:3] |> unlist() |> unique()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply `unique()` to a `data.frame`, the retruned value will be
a `data.frame` containing all unique rows of the data frame.

```r
dfa <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 3), b = c(1, 1, 3, 3))
dfa
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 1
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 3 3

unique(dfa)
#>   a b
#> 1 1 1
#> 2 2 1
#> 3 3 3
```

In the example above `unique()` detects rows 3 and 4 as being duplicated and reduces
them to one row.

If you are interested in getting all unique values for each column of a
`data.frame` you’ll have to apply `unique()` specifically to each column.
`lapply()` can be used for that.

```r
lapply(dfa, unique)
#> $a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 1 3
```

If you want to find unique values and your data is spread across several
columns you can use `unlist()` to “flatten” the data first and apply unique
after.

```r
dfa |> 
  unlist() |> 
  unique()
#> [1] 1 2 3
```